# iOS App crashes when loading Mapkit map on device

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When adding a map anywhere in our project whether it be through a xib, storyboard or programmatically will crash the app. This crash occurs on a physical device but not in simulator.  If the map's alpha is set to 0 the app doesn't crash.  As soon as it is set to 1 it crashes with this cause:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[VKMapView layer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109695d60'
```

Environment: xcode 14.1,
OS Ventura 13.0.1,
MacBook Pro 16in 2019

Project:
Min iOS 14.3

Device:
iPhone 13 Pro,
iOS v 16.1.2

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: We've never had issues with how the maps where implemented, this just started happening recently and only on my device not my co-workers.  I think it's something to do with how the project is being built.  Builds from bitrise crash and the same with my xcode but builds from a colleague xcode does not.

Comment: That information still does not make your question on-topic without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a third party integration. We downgraded the version of that package and now we no longer have a crash.